# iOS: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP) error on refreshing tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am creating a pull-to-refresh feature to my tableview page. Refreshing steps are the following:

1. Call API and get data from the internet
2. Use data to create another call
3. Reload data on tableview using the data from step 2 using `tableView.reloadData()`

When pulled to refresh, it sometimes works but sometimes crashes with the error message `fatal error: Index out of range` in the console and `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` message is marked on the `if` block of code. I have no idea what is the error.

This is the function that error shows

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if feedList[indexPath.row].type == "announcement" {
        let cell = feedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "announcementCell") as! FeedCell
        cell.subjectLbl.text = "Announcement - "+feedList[indexPath.row].courseName
        cell.titleLbl.text = feedList[indexPath.row].title
        cell.dateLbl.text = "Posted on "+feedList[indexPath.row].date
        cell.courseImg.sd_setImage(with: feedList[indexPath.row].imgSrc)
        return cell
    }
    else if feedList[indexPath.row].type == "assignment" {
        let cell = feedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "assignmentCell") as! FeedCell
        cell.subjectLbl.text = "Assignment - "+feedList[indexPath.row].courseName
        cell.titleLbl.text = feedList[indexPath.row].title
        cell.dateLbl.text = "Due date "+feedList[indexPath.row].dueDate!
        cell.courseImg.sd_setImage(with: feedList[indexPath.row].imgSrc)
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = feedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "materialCell") as! FeedCell
        cell.subjectLbl.text = "Material - "+feedList[indexPath.row].courseName
        cell.titleLbl.text = feedList[indexPath.row].title
        cell.dateLbl.text = "Posted on "+feedList[indexPath.row].date
        cell.courseImg.sd_setImage(with: feedList[indexPath.row].imgSrc)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Notes:

`SDWebImage` library is installed

`FeedCell` is the class inherited from `UITableViewCell`

`feedList` structure is like this `[(type:String, courseName:String, imgSrc:URL, title:String, date:String, dueDate:String?)]`

`cell.subjectLbl`, `cell.titleLbl`, `cell.dateLbl` and `cell.courseImg` are outlets in `FeedCell`

Comment: Take a look at you're datasource. You are trying to get access to the element of the array that is not in the array. Example array contains 5 elements and you try to access 7 element